# NGinx reverse proxy and subdomains on apache2

Tags: apache2, proxy, nginx

I currently have an nginx VM setup to route traffic between 3 domains but am having an issue with routing the subdomains at the moment. The current configuration goes PFSense -> nginx reverse proxy -> apache2. I am able to access the root domain fine but any time I enter a subdomain I am routed to the root instead.

Here is my server block configuration, there are some additional items in there because I need to be able to handle websockets as well.

```
    server
{
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name .mydomain.com;

        location /
        {
                proxy_pass http://<internal_server>;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
}

server
{
        listen 443 default_server;

        server_name .mydomain.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/secure/nproxy.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/secure/nproxy.key;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache       builtin:1000    shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols   TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers     HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/secureproxy.log;

        location /
        {
                proxy_pass http://<internal_server>;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While `nginx` supports wildcards and regular expression in `server_name`, you still have to specify the subdomain while proxying. This can be done using the `$host` variable:

```
server {
    server_name .mydomain.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$host;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/$host-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/all-hosts-error.log;
}
```

This will proxy a request for `foo.mydomain.com` to in an internal `foo.mydomain.com`. If the internal and external domains don't match, use a grouped regular expression:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.mydomain\.com$;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$subdomain.internal.host;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/$host-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/all-hosts-error.log;
}
```

Comment: I've been doing the proxy_pass by IP, is domain required to make this work?

Comment: @user186658 How does your internal server process subdomains?

Comment: Apache virtualhosts. The proxy configuration is new, I previously just did a NAT passthrough directly to my apache server.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to use domains.

Comment: Now I feel stupid....the subdomain is set to only listen for https but the proxy_pass directive is passing to http. Thank you for the information though, I will probably end up converting to domain translation since it will likely be more flexible in the future.

Comment: @user186658 Ah. In my case, some subdomains are handled by the same server and some by others. So I rely on DNS to handle that. If *all* your subdomains are handled by the same server, you don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Between making modifications based on this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/598202/make-nginx-to-pass-hostname-of-the-upstream-when-reverseproxying

and re-reading my configuration I managed to get it working.